# Multiple localhost config settings

Tags: assets, config, multi-environment

Me and my coworker work on the same Craft project.

We work locally with MAMP but access the database online, which works fine.

For the assets I'd like to define separate localhost basepaths, since we don't have the same folder structure.

Is there a way to make this work or do I need to work with IP's instead of localhost?

I'd also be open to set the assets relative instead of absolute to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [multi environment config](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-multi-environment) guide that I think will accomplish all you need.

It allows for environment specific DB connection parameters, but can also set filepaths, that why you can keep your assets path relative in regards to the path set in the environment.

It's an extension to the multi-environment setup as discussed [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs).

If you have any questions after reading that, feel free to ask.

Comment: Very cool solution, thanks for pointing it out!